# The Phantom Knights of Cloven Helm; can it activate more than once?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Does [The Phantom Knights of Cloven Helm](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/The_Phantom_Knights_of_Cloven_Helm) gain 500 attack every time a phantom monster is sent to the graveyard or just once whilst its on the field?

Answer (score 1):

**Each time**

[The Phantom Knights of Cloven Helm](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/The_Phantom_Knights_of_Cloven_Helm) you mention reads in its text:

> If a Phantom Knights card(s) is sent to your Graveyard: [gains 500 atk]

So that means the effect will trigger each time something sends one or more of such cards to the GY.

Worth noting the "card(s)" part: that means that if you send more than one card to the GY simultaneously, the monster will only gain 500 ATK (not 500 per card)